# Laravel profile access and permissions

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, authorization, access-control

How to make different page (& actions) access for different users in laravel?

For example we have 3 employees:

1. Admin - administrate eshop
2. Manager(s) - handles orders, shipping etc.
3. Copywriter(s) - add new goods to catalogue, write posts

**A)** Page access. When logging in eshop-admin area users see menu:

1. Admin - users settings posts catalogue shipping orders
2. Manager - posts catalogue shipping orders
3. Copywriter - posts catalogue

**B)** Actions access. Posts page for manager and copywriter:

1. Manager actions:

   - add_post
   - add_post_category
   - delete_post
   - edit_post
2. Copywriter:

   - add_post
   - edit_post

**C)** Grant permissions for delete post to copywriter A but not for other copywriters.

Comment: This is quite big and requires several tables and `Models` with other related things (Routes, Controllers etc), can you minimize the question or try something first and come up with code. Alternatively, you may use [ACL Packages](https://www.google.com.bd/search?q=laravel+acl+package&rlz=1C1KMZB_enBD539BD539&oq=laravel+acl&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j69i59j69i64.3441j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: At a higher level what you are looking for is called attribute-based access control (ABAC) and XACML which implements ABAC. For your use case, it could be overkill but it is the proper way of doing it. Check out csrc.nist.gov/projects/abac/. It is not specific to PHP or Laravel for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

The authorisation and permission part you could set-up using [Verify](https://github.com/Toddish/Verify-L4). Using that package you can create roles for the Admin, Manager and Copywriters.

To display the correct menu's, in the Controller or View you can check the role of the user and display/load the correct menu items.

In Verify you can set-up different permissions for each role (eg. add_post, edit_post etc.). So that will cover part B. You can create filters that check if the user has the correct permissions to eg. create a post.

Part C, you have to create a separate table/model in which you will record the post specific authorizations (post_id, user_id), and in the controllers action or again using a filter you need to check if the user and post appear in the table.